# Patching an entity and getting duplicate items

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm having problems with editing an entity. I have ObjectSpecifications that have different conditions. The problem I have has to do with the `DimensionalConditions`.

Whenever I edit an ObjectSpecification which has let's say "length: 1", and I try to add "width: 2" to it, the conditions end up being "length: 1, length: 1, width: 2".

Long story short, the conditions that were present before, get inserted again for some reason.

```
public ObjectSpecification modifySpecification(Long id, ObjectSpecificationRequest request) {
        ObjectSpecification objectSpecification = this.getObjectSpecificationById(id);
        return this.setSpecData(request, objectSpecification);
    }

public ObjectSpecification createSpecification(ObjectSpecificationRequest request){
        return this.setSpecData(request, new ObjectSpecification());
    }

public void deleteSpecification(Long id) {
        objectSpecificationRepository.delete(getObjectSpecificationById(id));
    }

public ObjectSpecification setSpecData(ObjectSpecificationRequest request, ObjectSpecification objectSpecification) {
        if (request.getName() != null) {
            objectSpecification.setName(request.getName());
        }

        if (request.getDimensionalConditions() != null) {
            List<DimensionalCondition> dimensionalConditions = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DimensionalCondition condition:request.getDimensionalConditions()) {
                DimensionalCondition dimensionalCondition = new DimensionalCondition();
                dimensionalCondition.setConditionType(condition.getConditionType());
                dimensionalCondition.setValue(condition.getValue());
                dimensionalCondition.setObjectSpecification(objectSpecification);
                dimensionalConditions.add(dimensionalCondition);
            }
            objectSpecification.setDimensionalConditions(dimensionalConditions);
        }

        if (request.getMechanisms() != null) {
            objectSpecification.setMechanismConditions(request.getMechanisms());
        }

        if (request.getServices() != null) {
            objectSpecification.setServiceConditions(request.getServices());
        }

        if (request.getWorkDetails() != null) {
            List<WorkDetail> workDetails = new ArrayList<>();
            for (WorkDetail workDetail:request.getWorkDetails()) {
                workDetails.add(workDetailService.getWorkDetailById(workDetail.getId()));
            }
            objectSpecification.setWorkDetailConditions(workDetails);
        }

        return objectSpecificationRepository.save(objectSpecification);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** This is a big update list there, make sure you merge your `ObjectSpecification` so that it is aligned with the `PersistenceContext` before you do any amendments.

**2)** You do not take under consideration the existing `DimensionalCondition` that are linked to `ObjectSpecification`. You always create a new one:

```
List<DimensionalCondition> dimensionalConditions = new ArrayList<>();
```

**3)** Make sure you have your cascading configured to `{PERSIST, MERGE}` at least on `@OneToMany List<DimensionalCondition>`.

Comment: I currently have CascadeType.ALL for point 3, that should cover persist and merge right?

Comment: I thought .setDimensionalConditions overwrites the data that was there previously, I don't really understand what to do.

Comment: It does not work that way. If you remove the parent, the children will get removed also, but if you just remove something from collection that will not touch anything already existing on the db. You have to explicitly remove what is not needed, just make sure you do that merge beforehand